# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_3/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,148,32]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature 
vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    #sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9)


model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',  
`optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), # Adam optimizer with 1.0e-4 learning rate
metrics = ['accuracy']) # Metrics to be evaluated by the model
```

When I compile the above code i get this error
Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_8/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,75,32].

I tried with the same padding and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure if you change

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150),padding='same'))
```

to

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150, 150, 3),padding='same'))
```

(you may have to change the shape of your data too)

it will work as intended.